# UECIDE: linker error with U8g2 library

Tags: arduino-ide, compilation-errors, avr-gcc, gcc, uecide

This sketch:

```
#include <SPI.h>
#include <Wire.h>
#include <U8g2lib.h>

//  OLED display.
U8G2_SSD1306_128X64_NONAME_1_HW_I2C u8g2(U8G2_R0, /* reset=*/ U8X8_PIN_NONE);    
void setup() {
  u8g2.begin();
}    
void loop() {  
}
```

Compile OK with Arduino 1.8.3, but under UECIDE 0.8.9-pre15 fails to link, with this message:

```
Compiling...
• Preprocessing...
• Compiling sketch...
• Compiling core...
‣ arduino
• Compiling libraries...
‣ U8g2 [/home/look/Documents/UECIDE/libraries/U8g2]
‣ SPI [/home/look/.uecide/libraries/Communications/arduino/SPI]
‣ U8g2 [/home/look/Documents/UECIDE/libraries/U8g2]
‣ Wire [/home/look/.uecide/libraries/Communications/arduino/Wire]
• Linking sketch...
/tmp/build-47290781-bacc-48e0-bc90-833910b26209/borrar.cpp.o: In function `U8G2::write(unsigned char)':
/home/look/Documents/UECIDE/libraries/U8g2/src/U8g2lib.h:248: undefined reference to `u8g2_DrawGlyph'
/tmp/build-47290781-bacc-48e0-bc90-833910b26209/borrar.cpp.o: In function `U8G2::initDisplay()':
/home/look/Documents/UECIDE/libraries/U8g2/src/U8g2lib.h:101: undefined reference to `u8x8_InitDisplay'
/tmp/build-47290781-bacc-48e0-bc90-833910b26209/borrar.cpp.o: In function `U8G2::clearDisplay()':
/home/look/Documents/UECIDE/libraries/U8g2/src/U8g2lib.h:104: undefined reference to `u8g2_ClearDisplay'
/tmp/build-47290781-bacc-48e0-bc90-833910b26209/borrar.cpp.o: In function `U8G2::setPowerSave(unsigned char)':
/home/look/Documents/UECIDE/libraries/U8g2/src/U8g2lib.h:107: undefined reference to `u8x8_SetPowerSave'
/tmp/build-47290781-bacc-48e0-bc90-833910b26209/borrar.cpp.o: In function `U8G2':
/home/look/Documents/UECIDE/libraries/U8g2/src/U8g2lib.h:62: undefined reference to `u8x8_ascii_next'
/home/look/Documents/UECIDE/libraries/U8g2/src/U8g2lib.h:62: undefined reference to `u8x8_ascii_next'
/tmp/build-47290781-bacc-48e0-bc90-833910b26209/borrar.cpp.o: In function `U8G2::home()':
/home/look/Documents/UECIDE/libraries/U8g2/src/U8g2lib.h:278: undefined reference to `u8x8_utf8_init'
/tmp/build-47290781-bacc-48e0-bc90-833910b26209/borrar.cpp.o: In function `U8G2_SSD1306_128X64_NONAME_1_HW_I2C':
/home/look/Documents/UECIDE/libraries/U8g2/src/U8g2lib.h:679: undefined reference to `u8g2_cb_r0'
/home/look/Documents/UECIDE/libraries/U8g2/src/U8g2lib.h:679: undefined reference to `u8g2_cb_r0'
/home/look/Documents/UECIDE/libraries/U8g2/src/U8g2lib.h:679: undefined reference to `u8g2_Setup_ssd1306_i2c_128x64_noname_1'
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
Compiling Fail
```

Both IDEs are set for Arduino Pro Mini 3.3V 8Mhz. In UECIDE I'm using GCC 4.9.2 for AVR. I copied the same U8g2 source code to both Arduino and UECIDE own libraries directory.

U8g2 library is version 2.15.2 by Oliver, installed via Arduino IDE and copied to the UECIDE libraries directory,

The problem, so far, only happens with U8g2 and not other libraries.

How do I solve this problem?

Comment: Can you provide a link to the exact version of U8g2 library you are using?

Comment: I'm using U8g2 library version 2.15.2 by Oliver, installed via Arduino IDE and copied to the UECIDE libraries directory,

Comment: Got it.  The layout of that library is a complete mess and uses a non-standard folder layout that UECIDE doesn't like. It's simple enough to clean it up though. I'll show you how.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The layout of that library is in a non-standard format with folders that UECIDE doesn't know to look for or how to deal with.

The main culpret is the inclusion of big chunks of code in a "clib" directory (why on earth?!?!) which doesn't get included in the compilation. Then on top of that you have header files in there that are referenced both from inside it and outside it.

The simplest fix is just to copy and move the files to better locations:

```
$ cd ~/Documents/UECIDE/libraries/U8g2/src
$ mv clib/*.c .
$ cp clib/*.h .
```

Note you *move* the source, but *copy* the headers. That's to get around the problem of the headers being referenced from two locations with relative paths.

The problem stems from UECIDE having (by necessity) much stricter rules than the Arduino IDE over the layout of a library. This is to facilitate better identification and categorization of the libraries so that recursive dependency detection can take place.

Comment: But UECIDE is just applying Arduino own rules about libraries, not inventing new ones. Am I right?

Comment: Arduino IDE is very lax with its rules. UECIDE is far more strict in what rules it applies. UECIDE applies what the Arduino specifies, but because Arduino doesn't really care people don't always follow those rules. They made it more complex and woolly by adding this new library format for cross architecture libraries which is just plain nasty.

Comment: Another big part of the problem is that, because the Arduino IDE has been so flippant with its own rules those rules have actually never been strictly defined anywhere. So it's very much a "best guess" as to what should and shouldn't be done. For instance: when do you recurse a source folder and when don't you? In an old library format you mustn't, because the source folder is the root. In the newer 1.5.x format you maybe could, but should you? It's not defined.

Comment: I am working on improving the file finding routines for libraries - get it to work better for newer style libraries.